# walking a binded directory tree in python

Tags: python, tree, directory

I want to walk a directory tree with python.
I found this solution.

```
def createIndex():
    fpath=open('config/path.conf','r')
    path=fpath.readline()
    indexstr=''
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path,True,None,True):
        indexstr = indexstr + 'directory : ' + dirname + '\n'
        for subdirname in dirnames:
            indexstr = indexstr + 'subdirectory :' + subdirname + '\n'
            for filename in filenames:
                indexstr = indexstr + 'file : ' + filename + '\n'
    return indexstr
```

It works really fine on my computer and on local test. But my aim is to to do the same on a remote server. The problem is, that on the remote server, the directory tree I want to walk is not a directory. I have done a chroot and a debootstrap on this server (NAS synology). I can use python only under the debian. But the directory tree I want to walk, is under DSM. So I did this `mount -o bind /volume1/music $CHROOT/music`
If I did a `ls` under my debian, I see the directories, but with os.walk of python it does not work. Even with followlinks = true (last argument of os.walk).

Does anyone have an idea?

EDIT: I found the problem, it comes from the `fpath=open('config/path.conf','r') path=fpath.readline()` path value is '../music_vibration\n' instead of '../music_vibration'

Sorry for this crap error, and thank you for your attention

Comment: What does `os.listdir` return for that directory? What about `os.system('ls')`? (You shouldn't do that in real code, but it's a good quick test.) Also, this may seem stupid, but are you sure your Python script is running in the same chroot jail as the shell you tested `ls` in?

Comment: `os.listdir` returns an array with all files and directories of my "root" directory. `os.system('ls')` returns the same as `ls`
Yeah the python script is running on the same jail (python is not installed on the 'base' system)

Comment: So the problem is that is sees the directories, but can't tell they're directories, I guess? Try `print [(os.stat(x).st_mode, os.lstat(x).st_mode) for x in os.listdir(path)]` and see if they have the `S_IFDIR` bit for either or both.

Comment: File "listdir.py", line 3, in main
     print [(os.stat(x).st_mode, os.lstat(x).st_mode) for x in os.listdir('../music_vibration')]
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'AlbumArt_{C6457A2C-D255-4930-92FA-A44A67830B4F}_Large.jpg'

Comment: I think that the problem is that it sees directory and files. But can not access it. I find this very strange, and what is the point of `mount -o bind` if any script can not use as directories / files.

Maybe should I do find a better solution for mounting my root directory in the jail chroot, than to change my python source ? What do you think about this idea ?

Comment: I found something interesting. The remote server is synology NAS. It works under a strange friendly-user linux distribution created by synology named DSM. I've installed python on this server. So I have tried to use my script without the chroot jail. And it's not working too. So the problem does not come from the chroot jail but from the DSM OS. It's like if os.walk() does not work on DSM ...